# Disable anonymous users on Open Atrium?

Tags: distributions

first off I'm a beginner to Open Atrium, but am wondering if there is a simple way for all content on the site to require authenticated user permissions.

I'm building an open atrium 2 intranet and do not want anything but the login field accessible to anonymous users

I realize I can simply set the access permissions in every piece of content that is created, but this doesn't seem like a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to http://yoursite.com/admin/people/permissions and find the **"View published content"** permission, uncheck it for anonymous users and that should do the trick.

Comment: When I uncheck that and click save it just gets checked again.

Comment: That's strange behavior. Have you tried messing around with the permissions system that the Organic Groups module provides you? This should have been included and enabled in your Open Atrium installation profile.